# In spacemacs, how can I enable editorconfig-mode by default ？

Tags: spacemacs

Currently I use editorconfig in my projects, and every time I open emacs/spacemacs, I need to press `M-x` and enable editorconfig-mode manually.

How can I enable editorconfig-mode by default ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on http://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from gitter:

Add `(editorconfig-mode 1)` to `dotspacemacs/user-config` before the closing parenthesis